# What is the kernel matrix size for 10 samples in a 20-dimensional space?

Tags: math, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I don´t understand why the answer to this question is *10x10*. How do I compute this?

*We have 10 samples in a 20-dimensional space that we want to analyse with a kernel
method. How large is the kernel matrix?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have 10 samples in a 20-dimensional space that we want to analyse
>   with a kernel method. How large is the kernel matrix?

The way I find always the correct answer to this is the following:

**Think the Kernel matrix as a matrix that summarizes information about the samples. This information can be a mapping φ of the samples for example.**

---

**Example 1:** If you have 10 samples and you calculate the **correlation** matrix it will be 10x10

**Example 2:** If you have 10 samples and you calculate the **distance** matrix it will be 10x10

So the kernel matrix is something similar to this. It's a matrix that refers to the samples so if you have 10 samples it is going to be a 10x10 matrix.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought (from my little experience in Linear Algebra):

NOTE: I'll edit once I can access the [CodeGog](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) tool. Seems to be down right now. Also there seems to be a specific way to find the kernel matrix, but i'll stick to my linear algebra understanding.

So we have a 20-dimensional space, and if we go back to linear algebra:

`Let A be a m x n matrix.` We know that `dim(A) = rank(A) + null(A)`. It's also important to remember that the `columnspace of A = rowspace of A`, so it doesn't matter which way you think of it. Its also important to note that the `kernel matrix of A is the null(A)`.

So, since we only have 10 samples, we can conclude that the rank is only 10, which means since the dimension is 20, and we know that `dim(A) - rank(A) = null(A). The null(A) = 20 - 10 = 10.` So since the `null(A) is 10`, the `kernel matrix which as stated before is the null(A), must be 10x10`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not recognize this from the course I have been taking but it seems to be a solution to the problem.